# Finding the MLE of Uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution, estimators

> Let $x_{1} = 2.4$ , $x_{2} = 9.2$ , $x_{3} = 5.2$ , $x_{4} = 4.1$ , $x_{5} = 2.1$, $x_{6} = 3.1$ be the observed values of a random variable of size 6 from the uniform distribution with parameters $(\theta -2,\theta + 6)$ where $\theta>0$  is unknown, then the $MLE$ of $\theta$ is :

I know that for finding MLE we have to differentiate and maximise the logarithm of the likelihood function w.r.t the parameter. But for this question how do you find the likelihood function with the parameter $\theta$ involved.

The PDF of the uniform function is as follows: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{8}$$

Or is there a different way in solving this question?

Comment: Try writing the pdf in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: @Sycorax how do you do that? I am unaware

Comment: HINT: Look at one of the answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473980/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-theta-for-uniform-distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the random variables $X_{1}, X_{2},..., X_{6}$ are independent draws from $Unif(\theta-2,\theta+6)$ with $\theta>0$

Then the joint pdf of $X_{1}, X_{2},..., X_{6}$ can be written as

$$f(X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{6};\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{6}f(X_{i}) = \prod_{i=1}^{6}\frac{1}{8}\mathbb{I}_{X_{i}\in(\theta-2,\theta+6)}$$

where $\mathbb{I}_{X_{i}\in(\theta-2,\theta+6)}=1$ if $X_{i}\in(\theta - 2,\theta  +6)$ and $0$ otherwise.

The goal is to maximize $f(X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n};\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$.

If all $X_{i}$ are outside the interval $(\theta-2,\theta+6)$ then all the indicator functons will be zero hence $f(X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n};\theta)=0$

So, for maximizing the pdf all the $X_{i}$ must be inside the interval $(\theta-2,\theta+6)$. For that to be true the following inequalities must hold

$$\theta-2\leq min(X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{6})$$ and
$$max(X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{6})\leq \theta +6$$

$$\Rightarrow \theta \in [3.2,4.1]$$

The derived interval $[3.2,4.1]$ is the only interval that makes the likelihood function $f(X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n};\theta)$ being non-zero as it let all the indicator functions equal to $1$.

Just to make sure that the values inside the interval $[3.2,4.1]$ are the ones that maximize the likelihood function $f(X_{1}, X_{2},...,X_{n};\theta)$ we can numerically observe that

```
x = c(2.4 , 9.2 , 5.2 , 4.1 , 2.1,3.1) 
theta = seq(0.1,10,by=0.1)  
like = rep(1,length(theta)) 
for(i in 1:length(theta)){  
for(j in 1:6){    
like[i] = like[i]*dunif(x[j], min = theta[i]-2, theta[i]+6 , log = FALSE) 
          }
                        } 
plot(like)
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this interval comprises the only values of $\theta$ with positive likelihood, let alone maximum likelihood

Comment: @Henry Would I be correct that the negative log-likelihood has nonzero values outside of this interval because the values are summed?

Comment: @COOLSerdash perhaps if you count infinity, i.e. $-\log(0)$, as non-zero

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but what then is the MLE of $\theta$ ?

Comment: I was wondering about that, is it possible to find a single Maximum Likelihood estimator, or all the values inside that interval can play the role of MLE? To me, it seems that all the $\theta \in [3.2,4.1]$ can be Maximum Likelihood estimators

Comment: @DBZrasengan16 If we keep in mind that the MLE estimator maximizes the likelihood function, then if you run the following code in R ```x = c(2.4 , 9.2 , 5.2 , 4.1 , 2.1,3.1)

theta = seq(0.1,10,by=0.1)

like = rep(1,length(theta))
for(i in 1:length(theta)){
 for(j in 1:6){
   like[i] = like[i]*dunif(x[j], min = theta[i]-2, theta[i]+6 , log = FALSE)
}
}
like
plot(like)``` You will observe that the maximum of the likelihood is attained inside the displayed interval, and is the same for all $\theta \in [3.2,4.1]$

Comment: @Fiodor1234 So if this question was to come for an examination and the options available were a) 3.5   b) 4.5 and c) 5.5  ; Is the answer then option $a$ ?

Comment: @DBZrasengan16 Yes the answer would be $a$